# There is an index created using Lucene, need to query from Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an existing web application which uses Lucene to create indexes. Now as per the requirement, I have to set up Solr which will serve as a search engine for many other web application including my web app. I do not want to create indexes within Solr. Hence, I need to tell Solr to read indexes from Lucene instead of creating indexes within Solr and reading from its own.

I'm learning Apache Solr. Is it possible? If it is, can you explain how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just have to:

1. use Solr standalone
2. go throught the process of creating an schema.xml that matches the index created in Lucene

I guess you will need to spend a couple of hours iteratively tweaking schema.xml/solrconfig.xml and restarting/reloading till you are able to query from Solr. Make sure you use the right analyzers.

Comment: Do I need to change dataDir, in solrconfig.xml?

Comment: absolutely!! among possible several other things